# Unable to display Widget when passing this as the parent when initiating

Tags: c++, qt

Hi Im learning QT and I have come across something I don't understand. why is it when I create a widget like so

```
widget = new Widget(this);
```

`widget->show();`doesn't display the widget, but if I leave the 'this' out i.e

```
widget = new widget();
```

It does display? whats more I need to be able to call one of the parent's methods from the child and unless I set the patient of the child by passing `this` upon its creation I am unable to do this.

Comment: This is a window i.e. QMainWindow

Answer (score 0):

The widget does show up. But it shows up as part of the main window, not in its own window. Of course if the widget you're creating doesn't have any content in it, then you won't see much. You can test this with something like:

```
widget = new QTextEdit(this);
widget->show();
```

If you want to make the widget always show up in its own window, then you should have your widget inherit from QDialog instead of from QWidget. Or, if you don't want (or can't) do this, then you should set the `Qt::Window` window flag when creating the widget:

```
widget = new Widget(this, Qt::Window);
```